# RxJava: Merge an observable with a completable based on the result of the first emission of the observable

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have an observable that continually emits but I need to run a completable on a condition based on the first emission of the observable. The observable will continue to emit even when the completable has completed. I have tried looking around for an operator that does this, but I can't find one. How can I possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that -

```
observable
  .flatMap(value -> {
     return (value == something ? completableThatDoesSomething : Completable.complete())
       .andThen(Observable.just(value));
  })
```